# What's the difference between 'fowl' and 'poultry'?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns, word-usage

As the title says, I'm interested in the semantic difference between these two words.

OALD gives the definition of *fowl* as "a bird that is kept for its meat and eggs, for example a chicken."

*Poultry* is defined by the same dictionary as "chickens, ducks and geese, kept for its meat and eggs."

While the two definitions sound quite identical to me, my understanding of the difference between them is that *fowl* is more narrowly focused on a bird being treated as a single object, but at the same time allows for the flexibility of the semantic content of the word, so that the word is not rigidly associated with and applied to any specific kind of birds.

*Poultry* in turn seems to treat the object in its plurality and also to have some minor constrictions on its semantics, thus limiting a wide notion to a number of particular cases.

With all that said, I ask that you either confirm or deny the validity of my intuitive explanation for the question I'm seeking the answer to.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think there's another difference: *poultry* is a subset of *fowl*.  Either *poultry* or *fowl* can refer to domesticated or farmed animals.  When referring to wild game, however, (e.g., pheasant, partridge, wild turkey), *fowl* is more applicable, whereas *poultry* is not.

Merriam-Webster's defines as follows:

> **poultry**: domesticated birds kept for eggs or meat
>
> **fowl**: (1) a bird of any kind (2) any of several domesticated or wild
>   gallinaceous birds

Interestingly enough, my online dictionary says that gallinaceous includes "*domestic poultry and game birds*."

Comment: Does "game" mean "animal" in the expression "wild game" in your answer ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista it refers to animals that are hunted, specifically birds in this case.