# Why and when did "fowls" start being called "chickens"?

Tags: etymology

(Note: I've seen the question [What's the difference between 'fowl' and 'poultry'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61140/whats-the-difference-between-fowl-and-poultry) but I am not asking about the definition, rather the historical usage pattern.)

In modern English we talk about chickens (the bird) and chicken (the meat), as in a plate of chicken, or some chickens in a farmyard.

I read a lot of older novels, particularly from the early 19th c. (Dickens and so on) and have often noticed that they don't talk about chicken, or chickens.  The word "fowl" is used. For example, in Dickens' *Little Dorrit* there is a mention of "cold fowl or hot boiled ham"; in Wilkie Collins' *The Legacy of Cain* "he had a fowl for his dinner"; in Gaskell's *Cousin Phillis* there are "speckled fowls" pecking in the yard.

Nobody would call a chicken a fowl today, even less so when talking about the meat. And yet we still talk about pork, beef, etc. the same as ever. When did this terminology change, and why?

Comment: "Nobody would call a chicken a fowl today, even less so when talking about the meat". I do both. What does that make me?

Comment: The quoted references to “fowls” probably don’t refer to chickens at all, but some other bird that may be raised or hunted and eaten, such as grouse, pheasant, or pigeon, as mentioned in a comment below.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: a fowl mouth? 

Comment: Hare is fowl and fowl is hare; Easter must be in the air.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Chickens were called *chicken* before chickens were called *fowl*. *Fowl* emerged in early modern English, had a period of popularity, and then faded by the 20th century.

### Chicken

*Chicken* goes back to Old English, where it referred to the young of *gallus gallus domesticus* - the chick (Oxford English Dictionary, "[chicken, n."](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/31547)). By the late 14th century, *chicken* was used to refer to the adult chicken as well as the meat:

> 1381   Diuersa Servicia in C. B. Hieatt & S. Butler Curye on Inglysch (1985) 64   Nym kedys or **chekenys** & hew hem in morsellys.
>
> c1405  (▸c1387–95)    G. Chaucer Canterbury Tales Prol. (Hengwrt) (2003) l. 382   To boille the **chiknes** [c1415 Corpus Oxf. chikenes, c1430 Cambr. Gg.4.27 chekenys] with the Marybones.

This usage continued to the present day. Certainly there are quotes in the 18th and 19th century that show *chicken* didn't fade from fashion entirely at any point:

> 1760   T. Warton Idler 26 Jan. 25   The Company may..refresh themselves with cold Tongue, **Chicken**, and French Rolls.
>
> 1881   Judy 30 Mar. 155/1   Sloper had roast **chicken** for dinner.

### Fowl

*Fowl* is also from Old English, but it referred to *birds* more generically ("[fowl, n.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/74043)"). Only in the late 16th century did it emerge as a more specific term for domesticated birds like hens:

> a1586   Sir P. Sidney Arcadia (1590) iii. xxiii. sig. Xx3   As folkes keepe **foule**, when they are not fatte inough for their eating.

By the 17th century *fowl* could refer to meat as well:

> 1672   O. Walker Of Educ. i. xii. 160   A feast suggests..Fish, **Foul**, Flesh.

The OED notes that this usage isn't current except in set phrases like "fish, flesh, and fowl."

### What happened to fowl?

So *chicken* stayed around after *fowl* dropped off in usage. When did that happen? Perhaps in the early 20th century. For example, here is an NGram showing that chicken appears more in its corpuses after 1900:

[image]

As a coincidence, the OED entry for "chicken, n." also includes this quote from around the same time, which may suggest some middle-class snootiness toward *fowl*:

> 1908   Westm. Gaz. 24 Jan. 3/1   It is a disastrous betrayal of middle-class origin to speak of a ‘**chicken**’ as a ‘**fowl**’. Whatever the age of the bird, the word must always be **chicken**.

One quote doesn't prove any causality, though. It is also possible that farmers and grocery stores themselves tended toward *chicken* to refer to the specific animal and its meat, whereas *fowl* persisted in a more generalized form to refer to *wild fowl* or *water fowl*.

Comment: *Fowl* is the section of fancy restaurant menus that contains those dishes that were prepared from the flesh of dinosaurs rather than that of mammals or that of fish or other seafood.

Comment: _Frigaliment Importing v. BNS Intl Sales Corp._ (1960), a breach-of-contract case, offers an interesting take on the issue of "chicken" v. "fowl." As the appellate court's opinion observes, "The issue is, what is chicken? [The Swiss] Plaintiff says 'chicken' means a young chicken, suitable for broiling and frying. [The U.S.] Defendant says 'chicken' means any bird of that genus that meets contract specifications on weight and quality, including what it calls 'stewing chicken' and plaintiff pejoratively terms 'fowl'. Dictionaries give both meanings, as well as some others not relevant here."

Comment: Perhaps it indicates a period where "fowl" on the menu might mean grouse or pheasant or pigeon in addition to chicken.  Those other birds were far more commonly eaten than they are now.   Saying something is "fowl" allows you to be non-specific in a similar way to how these days you might see something sold as a "meat pie" without indicating what meat it is.

Comment: @EricNolan agreed. And if I saw "fowl" today I'd assume some unspecified bird(s) were used to source the meat, and not solely chicken

Comment: Should it be "Gallus gallus domesticus," with the genus capitalized?

Comment: Peacocks and peahens are collectively pea fowl. There are also Guinea fowl. Probably others. Might also refer to ducks, geese, etc.

Comment: Not sure if this is correct concerning fowl emerging as a more specific term for domesticated birds, as red jungle fowls that chickens originate from are still called that. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_junglefowl

Comment: *"a chicken in every pot"* because they're for rich people. Used to call it [*poultry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poultry_farming) and technically still do. *All chickens are fowls. Not all fowls are chickens.* And no other fowl is as good, nor grows as large faster. What happened to 'fowl' was, in a word: Perdue (est. 1920).

Comment: Might be interesting to note that the cognate words in German are *Vogel* (to fowl), meaning very generally *bird* (which matches the pre-1600s generic meaning claimed here); and *Küken* (to chicken), meaning very generally a juvenile bird (as in ... well, chick), which matches the original meaning here. Seems like the German language kept close to the original meaning while the English language meanders back and forth through the ages.

Answer (score 9):

#### Could be a false assumption

You're assuming that all references to "fowl" refer to chickens.  This is not true. Small game birds such as pheasant, partridge or pigeon could equally well be described as "fowl".  They taste fairly similar, so there is less need to distinguish them when it comes to describing someone's meal.

As for "speckled fowls pecking in the yard", also consider that they could be [guinea fowl](https://www.rarebreeds.co.nz/guineafowl.html) which are almost always speckled and which were introduced to Britain in the 15th century.  They were much less common than chickens, but the time of Gaskell were certainly well-known everywhere.

Comment: For that matter, pretty much *all* birds commonly domesticated or hunted for meat or eggs are referred to as "fowls", so ducks, geese, swans, turkeys, peacocks, ostriches, etc. would all qualify.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman True enough.  Most of those are a bit larger though (and often more expensive!) so they'd warrant a special mention at a meal.  For birds which are just "the gardener shot something in the woods yesterday", they're a bit more commonplace. :)

Comment: Not swans, if the story is set among commoners in the UK.  Swans have a unique status in the UK, in that they are exclusive property of HM the Queen (with minor exceptions). These days that serves more as wildlife protection though.

Comment: @user_1818839 Probably not turkeys in the UK either, since they're mostly new world birds, but I was just talking in general.  Swans may be referred to in the US as "water fowl" even if you're not planning on eating them.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Capercaillie on the other hand (Tetrao urogallus, forest dweller) ... many years ago (too long to remember the reference) I saw an account of a Highland shooting trip that bagged one, leading to a highly anticipated and possibly unique banquet, only to find (on carving the fowl) that its exclusive diet of pine needles filled the room with an intense stink of turpentine, and the meat was quite inedible.